# I have this python script, I'd rather use JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python

I have this chunk of Python that I cobbled together from various sources (I am not a programmer or developer or even in any kind of technical trade, I just needed something to automate some processes).  This is not the actual specific script, but it's written and works the same way:

```
import os
os.system('cls')

from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

print "MADLIBS!"

print "If %r exists, it will be erased." % filename
print "To abort, hit CTRL-C (^C)."
print "To proceed, hit RETURN."

raw_input("?")

os.system('cls')

print "Opening file %r..." % filename
target = open(filename, 'w')

print "Overwriting file %r." % filename
target.truncate()

analyst = raw_input("Please enter the title of this madlib: ")
appdate = raw_input("Please enter your name: ")
print

print "Thank you.  Please enter the following information:"
print

verb    = raw_input("   Enter a verb:           ")
noun    = raw_input("   Enter a noun:           ")


print "Thank you."


target.write("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd'>")
target.write("\n")
target.write("<html xml:lang='en' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' lang='en'>")
target.write("\n")
target.write("<head>")
target.write("\n")
target.write("<meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'/>")
target.write("\n")
target.write(appdate)
target.write("'s Madlib story!")
target.write("<p>")
target.write("Go ")
target.write(verb)
target.write(" a ")
target.write(noun)
target.write(".")

target.write("<p>")
target.write("<p>")
target.write("<p>")

target.write("<a href='javascript:window.print()' title='Send to printer'>Send to printer</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;")
target.write("\n")
target.write("")
target.write("\n")
target.write("<script language='VBScript'>")
target.write("\n")
target.write("    Sub Window_Onload")
target.write("\n")
target.write("      window.opener = 'x'")
target.write("\n")
target.write("    End Sub")
target.write("\n")
target.write("</script>")
target.write("\n")
target.write("")
target.write("\n")
target.write("\n")

target.write("<a href='javascript:self.close()' title='Close this window'>Close this window</a>")
target.write("\n")

target.write("</body>")
target.write("\n")
target.write("</html>")

target.close()
os.system(filename)
```

It creates an HTML document using input gathered from the user via Python.  It essentially does what I want it to do, but I'm starting to think Python is not the best route to get what I want here (I only created the script because I was curious about Python and wanted to try creating something).  Can anyone give any general advice on doing something similar using JavaScript (rather than Python) to gather user input *in* a browser window and display it *to* the browser window?

I realize there is a certain amount of general clumsiness with the way the code is put together and it's not particularly elegant, but that's something I can deal with later.  For now, I'd just like a JavaScript version of it to work so I can tweak and refine it later. Any suggestions?

Comment: Its mostly print statements.  Use a templating language.  Both JS and Python support several.

Comment: What question are you asking? It sounds like you're asking us to translate your script to JS, which isn't a great fit for SO.

Comment: My humble suggestion: hire a JavaScript developer.

Comment: Learn a bit of JavaScript reading a good tutorial (e.g. http://eloquentjavascript.net/) and give it a shot? Not sure what kind of answer you expect and what exactly you deem as "easy".

Comment: Have you looked into python web frameworks like Flask?  Not sure how much logic you want on the client-side, but you could keep it pretty clean HTML with a static form, then capture that data on the web server and process it in python.

Comment: I guess I'm asking if there is an easy way to do this in Javascript, or a way at all.  I don't want anyone else to do it for me, but I've been hunting for a while now for a way to do this in Javascript and I can't seem to find anything that fits my needs.

Comment: If you have python and want javascript, try converting it with PythonJs which supports Python 2.7, see https://github.com/PythonJS/PythonJS#2-translatorpy.  An alternative is Pyjs, however it only supports most of Python 2.5 and some of 2.6, but that may not be an issue with simple Python code, see see http://pyjs.org/.

Answer (score 0):

This is about as basic as it gets in JavaScript. Here's a snippet with a rough translation of your code.

```js
var appdate = prompt("Please enter your name:");
var verb = prompt("Enter a verb:");
var noun = prompt("Enter a noun:");
var story = appdate + "'s Madlib story!<p>Go " + verb + " a " + noun + ".";
document.getElementById("madLib").innerHTML = story;
```

```html
<div id="madLib">
</div>
```